# Connect limit's series in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

**Updated** :I'm trying to make a radar chart with hightcharts, but I can't connect this values(the ones which has asterisks for example):

```js
        $('#container').highcharts({    
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        chart: {
            polar: true,
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Graph',
            x: -80
        },
        pane: {
            size: '80%'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["Sponsor / Developer","Banks","SPV","Bank Legal DD","Services Legal contracts","Environmental license","Grid connection license","Construction License","Generation License","Site Studies\/License","Property\/terrain","Technical studies","EPC","Financial model"],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            lineWidth: 0                        
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
            lineWidth: 0,
            min: 0            
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            pointFormat: '<span style=\'color:{series.color}\'>{series.name}: <b>\${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 70,
            layout: 'vertical'
        },                        
        series: [{"name":"Legal","data":[4,3,4,4,4,4,4,null,null,null,null,null,null,4],"color":"#206ef0"},{"name":"Licenses and Permits","data":[null,3,null,null,null,4,4,4,4,4,4,null,null,null],"color":"#f07820"},{"name":"Technical","data":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,4,4,4,null],"color":"#ff0000"},{"name":"Financial","data":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]}]});
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

The goal is to connect the series'limit of any series. I mean, if in excel I have the same series, **financial model** and **Sponsor/Developer** will be connected by a blue line. Look :
[excel graph](http://postimg.org/image/4y7vaeifn/)
How can I do it?
Thank you.

Comment: The values are not linked, because between points are null value. Remove this value and then print. Per each point you can use array with pair [x,y] instad of y only.

Comment: I Just edited my question. It has the code running. for instance, when I create this graph in excel and I have the same series, **financial model** and **Sponsor/Developer** will be connected by a blue line

Comment: I also added an excel image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the chart you can use scatter serie with enabled lineWidth. After last point, add reference to first point, then line will be printed.

```
{
        "name": "Legal",
        "data": [[0,4], [1,3], [2,4], [3,4], [4,4], [5,4], [6,4], null, null, null, null, null, null,[13,4],[0,4]],
        "color": "#206ef0"
}
```

You can set line on the edge, by setting tickInterval / endOnTick / max options.

```
yAxis: {
        max:4,
        tickInterval:1,
        endOnTick:true,
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rLfj69b9/8/